# HTML Audio stop IOS music player when use play()

Tags: javascript, html, ios, reactjs, audio

I'm using html audio to play the beep sound on timer app by using `audioElement.play()`, which the user is already interact with the screen to enable sound (press unmute button). This web application is a fitness timer so I aim to use it with the other music player app to play in the backgrounds.

On Android, the music volume turned down when the beep sound is played and turn back up automatically.

On IOS, when the beep sound played the music completely stops and not playing after.

Is there a workaround to play the audio without stoping the IOS media player?

Answer (score 1):

Since @Expl0de's answer is rather short, I'll try to give an example. Since it does not register as a music track (although I could not find any reference for that), using the **Web Audio API** shouldn't stop any music being played in the background.

There are numerous ways to play audio through the API, the two most simple ones for audio files are listed below:

```js
const mediaElement = document.getElementById("audio");
const url = mediaElement.src;
let sourceBuffer;

const ctx = new AudioContext();

fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
  .then(arrayBuffer => ctx.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer))
  .then(audioBuffer => {
    sourceBuffer = ctx.createBufferSource();
    sourceBuffer.buffer = audioBuffer;
    sourceBuffer.connect(ctx.destination);
    document.getElementById("play-buffer").disabled = false;
  });

function playElement() {
  // To be honest, I have no idea, why this has to be in an event listener
  // Also, seems to have to be right before the play call for some reason
  // Does not make sense to me, I hope it's a quirk of the snippet environment
  mediaElement.addEventListener('play', () => {
    const sourceElement = ctx.createMediaElementSource(mediaElement);
    sourceElement.connect(ctx.destination);
  });
  mediaElement.play();
}

function playBuffer() {
  sourceBuffer.start();
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-bottom: 1em">
  <button onclick="playElement()">Play Element!</button>
  <button id="play-buffer" disabled onclick="playBuffer()">Play Buffer!</button>
</div>
<audio controls id="audio" src="https://mdn.github.io/webaudio-examples/media-source-buffer/viper.mp3" />
```

For more info, please refer to the pretty good [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) or the more hands-on [examples](https://github.com/mdn/webaudio-examples/). In particular, the example on [decoding audio data](https://github.com/mdn/webaudio-examples/tree/master/decode-audio-data) and the [media source buffer](https://github.com/mdn/webaudio-examples/tree/master/media-source-buffer) probably match best what you are trying to achieve.