# HTML Audio stops IOS music player after calling audio.play()

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I am aware that there is a very similar question asked ([HTML Audio stop IOS music player when use play()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60173678/html-audio-stop-ios-music-player-when-use-play)) but they didn't seem to elaborate after finding their solution using 'Web Audio API'. I was wondering if someone would be able to elaborate and explain how to allow IOS music player to continue playing ask calling audio.play() and the audio finishing.

Thanks

Comment: I realize you might not be able to comment yet, but this is a question definitely more fitting for a comment. I'll post one, I think it's better to track answers on the original topic

Comment: If the author does not elaborate shoot me a message, I might be able to clarify the answer when I find some free time.

Comment: The post was posted around a year ago and the user doesn't seem to be active on the account. If its fine with you and when you are free, do you mind elaborating/discussing on how to fix this type of issue? Thanks so much!

Comment: I just posted a more detailed answer, hope it helps you. Although it looks a bit overwhelming, the docs about it on MDN are really good and fairly easy to understand (still a lot though). Especially the examples help a lot